# Force a python package that uses requests to go through a proxy

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, meteostat

I am currently using the python package [meteostat](https://dev.meteostat.net/). It makes use of the requests package to download data off the meteostat servers. I am running this package through work a machine that needs to use an http proxy.

When running their example code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from meteostat import Stations, Monthly

# Set time period
start = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2018, 12, 31)

# Get Monthly data
data = Monthly('10637', start, end)
data = data.fetch()

# Plot line chart including average, minimum and maximum temperature
data.plot(y=['tavg', 'tmin', 'tmax'])
plt.show()
```

I get the following error at `data.fetch()`:

> URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory>

I believe this is due to the fact that I am not going through my work's proxy, like I have to when I install packages via pip.

I have tried adding the following to my code, but it did not resolve the issue:

```
import requests

proxies = {
   'http': 'WORK PROXY',
   'https': 'WORK PROXY',
}
```

Comment: Have you try [setting env varibables](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies)?

Comment: I added the "sessions" code but it did not work.

Comment: I'm talking about env variables. You can set the proxy as an env variable which the request library should use.

Comment: How do I do this? It was not clear from the guide you sent me.